# Elastic collisions voilate 3rd law of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

If a body of small mas $m_{1}$, collide with object of equal mass $m_{2}$ at rest , i.e $m_{1}= m_{2}$, then acc. to conservation of energy and momentum $m_{1}$ will come at rest while $m_{2}$ will start moving with same velocity (momentum) as that of $m_{1}$, however they both suffered equal force during collision acc.to third law. ???? and if reaction force is responsible for bringing $m_{1}$ at rest, then why this does not happens in case if $m_{1}\ll m_{2}$ ..( as $m_{1}$ bounces off )..???
although I agree and truly understand it in terms of energy and momentum, but unable to apply Newton's 3rd law here ...
(please try to explain in terms of forces only) ...

Comment: Energy is force by distance. Both the force and the distance are the same for both balls. If you understand the explanation in terms of energy, then divide energy by the distance (over which the force was in effect) and you would get the explanation in terms of forces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply Newton's 2nd law as well as the 3rd law.  If the masses involved in the collision are unequal the forces acting on each will still be of equal magnitude but the accelerations of each will be different.  This is why m1 does not have to be brought to rest.

Answer (score 0):

During the collision the force $\vec F_{21}$ on mass $m_2$ due to mass $m_1$ is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the force $\vec F_{12}$ on mass $m_1$ due to mass $m_2$ - Newton's third law.

$\vec F_{21} = - F_{12}$

The impulse on mass 2 due to mass 1 is $\displaystyle \vec I_{21} = \int_{\rm collision} \vec F_{21}\, dt$ and the impulse on mass 1 due to mass 2 is $\displaystyle \vec I_{12} = \int_{\rm collision} \vec F_{12}\, dt$.

Since the time for the collision is the same for both masses $\vec I_{21} = - \vec I_{12}$

Now the impulse is the change of momentum

$\vec  I_{21} = m_2\,\vec v_{2,\rm final} - m_2\,\vec v_{2,\rm initial}$ and $\vec  I_{12} = m_1\,\vec v_{1,\rm final} - m_1\,\vec v_{1,\rm initial}$

$\Rightarrow m_2\,\vec v_{2,\rm initial} +m_1\,\vec v_{1,\rm initial} =  m_2\,\vec v_{2,\rm initial} + m_1\,\vec v_{1,\rm final}$

which means that the change in momentum of mass 1 must be equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the change in momentum of mass 2.

Now you need to see what will happen if mass 2 starts off at rest and is hit by mass 1 travelling at a velocity $v_{1,\rm initial}$.

$m_1\,\vec v_{1,\rm initial} =  m_2\,\vec v_{2,\rm initial} + m_1\,\vec v_{1,\rm final}$

So the initial momentum that mass 1 had now needs to be equal to the sum of the momenta of masses 1 and 2.

Let us see if it possible to bring mass 1 to rest.

ie $m_1\,\vec v_{1,\rm initial} =  m_2\,\vec v_{2,\rm final} \Rightarrow v_{2,\rm final} = \dfrac {m_1}{m_2} \,v_{1,\rm initial}$

The change in kinetic energy $\Delta E = \dfrac 12 m_2\, v_{2,\rm final}^2 - \dfrac 12 m_1\, v_{1,\rm initial}^2 \Rightarrow \dfrac 12m_1\, v_{\rm 1,initial}^2\left( \dfrac{m_1}{m_2} - 1\right)$

When $m_1=m_2$ there is no loss in collision as the collision is elastic as you have pointed out but you will note that if $m_2>m1$ then it is possible for mass 1 to stop after the collision provided that the right amount of kinetic energy is lost to the system.

The same event can happen even  if $m_1>m_2$ but then you must have a super-elastic collision where the system gains kinetic energy which in theory could be arraged by having an initially compressed spring between the two masses or a contrilled explosion just as the masses collide!